# Android StringTokenizer - reading blank values

Tags: java, android, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I have pipe delimited strings containing id, latitude, longitude, refname, userid, username:

```
1390|-32.5506782531738|18.9797592163086|Hardie - Vrede 4|21|Hardie van der Merwe
1391|-33.5143165588379|18.422327041626|test|3|sgroenewald
1392||||3|sgroenewald
```

When I use a StringTokenizer class to read each of these lines, they work, until I hit line 3, where there are blank values. I read the ID ok, then I check hasMoreTokens(), which returns true, but it skips over the blanks and goes to the second last field, which is read as 3 using nextToken, but into the wrong variable in my code.

Continuing on I read the next field using nextToken, expecting it to be longitude, but I get a string back (sgroenewald) and the wheels come off..

Is there a way to see if the next token is blank, before reading it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [constructor of StringTokenizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) with 3 params, specifying `returnDelimiters` as `true`. Of course you need to manually remove delimiters from values itself while cycling tokenizer.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping StringTokenizer was going to do the work for me. I'll use as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is, replaces these blank spaces with no space ( " " with "" ) using replace() method of String Class.

String finalStr = "1390|-32.5506782531738|18.9797592163086|Hardie - Vrede 4|21|Hardie van der Merwe";

```
finalStr = finalStr.replaceAll( " ", "" );
```

Comment: There aren't any spaces in the blank fields. I've put the sample into code formatting so maybe its more clear.

Comment: If you look at line 3, there's nothing between the | - not even spaces. Replacing " " with "" will only corrupt the names fields by removing all spaces.

Comment: in that case it will not replace anything, so your problem will be solved :)

Comment: I'll still have ||| which will cause StingTokenizer to skip ahead and not return the null values?

Comment: @HeinduPlessis, then you may replace that as well using same replace() method